# What is the best approach to style code output in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a set of Jupyter notebooks I am developing using iPython as the underlying Kernel.

I want to style the output to make it stand out from the surrounding text, what is the best way to style my output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a `custom.css` file in the `~/.jupyter/custom` folder which will affect the css.

To style the output, you'll need to use a selector like so:

```
.output_subarea * {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Depending on what you want to style. The `*` matches all elements and the space between `.output_subarea` and `*` indicates we want to select the decendents of `.output_subarea`. `!important` indicates that we want to override any existing styles, you may need to use this. If it doesn't seem to be working, try adding on `!important` like so:

```
.output_subarea * {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

There's a couple of output selectors, you should play around with them until you find the one you want to use.

`.output` selects the whole output div, `.output_area` selects any output areas. Usually styling `.output` or `.output_area` will do similar things.

`.output_subarea` specifically only targets areas of actual outputs (i.e. it will exclude the prompt)

Play around with it, have a look at the DOM inspector using your browser to find the classes of the parts of the page you want to affec